# agora-react-native-rtm is throwing issue related to merged manifest

Tags: react-native, agora.io

The dependencies used in the project are

```
  "dependencies": {
    "agora-react-native-rtm": "^1.5.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-agora": "^3.7.0"
  },
```

Error log is

> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> D:\Desktop\Codes\AgoraDemo\agorademo\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
> Error:
> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to
> specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the
> corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details.

Here is the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

BTW: Project works fine if all the agora related dependencies is removed

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
For SDK 31 there is some issue with the  "react-native-agora": "^3.7.0" version which will be fixed in a new one, meanwhile you can proceed with the workaround
https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/react-native-agora/issues/496#issuecomment-1126508840